# Giving away from own Reputation Point as a Present

Tags: feature-request

If it would be possible, I would love to give away from my own reputation points as a gift whom have helped me very much indeed. It is almost like a shame that, I could not pay them for their each hard works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

1. Nobody here comes expecting to be paid.
2. Upvotes give reputation; so does accepting answers.
3. You can "pay it forward" by providing answers yourself.
4. You can also "pay it forward" by [offering bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) on questions (your own or other people's) and awarding them to answers you find particularly helpful. You probably don't want to overdo it, though: bounties are meant to be special. If there are too many bounties, they defeat the purpose of calliing attention to particularly worthy/interesting questions.

   This would probably be the closest to "giving away reputation" that you can come up with under the current set-up.

Comment: Or perhaps, "Nobody who comes here expecting to be paid stays for long"...